# Why does docker issue a "forbidden path" error?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to work my way through a Docker tutorial using boot2docker on OS X 10.8.4. But I keep getting a "forbidden path" error when running `docker build .` from within the app directory.

Here is my docker client.:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 0.8.0, build cc3a8c8
```

Here is my app directory:

```
$ tree
.
├── Dockerfile
├── index.html
├── index.js
└── package.json
```

But, when I run docker build I get this output.

```
$ docker build .
Uploading context 6.144 kB
Uploading context
Step 0 : FROM dockerfile/nodejs
 ---> ec3f14b7134c
Step 1 : ADD . /src
2014/02/07 09:58:27 build: Forbidden path outside the build context: . (/mnt/sda1/tmp/docker-build854689076)
```

Notice that I'm trying to add a relative path: `ADD . /src`.
This seems pretty straightforward, and I've seen this kind of `ADD` statement in a few examples, so I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest release of boot2docker.  See also https://github.com/steeve/boot2docker/issues/143 for more details of the problem (which is that /tmp is a symlink and has to be resolved for Docker to work properly, which boot2docker 0.5.4 fixes).

Comment: `boot2docker download` will fetch the latest version, in which this issue is resolved.

Comment: in docker mac beta seems to be this is still an issue

Comment: i have the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
failed to build: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../mysql/dumps ()